# setInterval - if element has class externd interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hi i use the following function which loads a javascript every 10 seconds and changes the visibility of some elements:

```
function folienwechsel(){
    if ($("section:last-child").hasClass('active') ) {
            $("section.active").hide();
            $("section.active").removeClass("active").prevUntil("first").show().addClass("active");
    } else {
            $("section.active").hide();
            $("section.active").removeClass("active").next().show().addClass("active");             
    };
}

setInterval(function(){
folienwechsel()}, 10000)
```

Now i want to extend this to extend an interval if an element has a class like "video". Do you have any advice how to do that?

Thx for your help

Comment: You don't have to wrap the function in an anonymous function. Just pass it, like this: `setInterval(folienwechsel, 10000);`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try something like this :

```
var myInterval;

function folienwechsel() {
    if ($("section:last-child").hasClass('active')) {
        $("section.active").hide();
        $("section.active").removeClass("active").prevUntil("first").show().addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("section.active").hide();
        $("section.active").removeClass("active").next().show().addClass("active");
    };


    if ($("section:last-child").hasClass('video')) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        myInterval = setInterval(function() {
                folienwechsel()
            }, 2000) //Updated interval
    } else {
        //In other scenarios you may need to reset it.
        myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            folienwechsel()
        }, 10000)
    }
}
myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    folienwechsel()
}, 10000);
```

Comment: how does it answer the question about the `video`?

Comment: `if ($("section:last-child").hasClass('video')) {` if element has class video then it will clear earlier interval and create a new one, ain't you looking for this thing?

Comment: It was copy paste mistake, have updated my answer :) have a look and do let me know if you find any issue. :)